# Where can I create a directory without admin rights?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems

I am trying to create a directory with my program, but the program will not be run under admin. Where in the Windows file system can I create a directory and write to the directory without admin rights?

Comment: It depends on what your use is. Is this a file per user or per machine?

Comment: @David This is a file that will only be accessed by the currently logged in account at the time of directory creation.

Comment: So you need to save it somewhere under the user profile.

Comment: [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) is what you're looking for.

Comment: So if the the user "John" is logged in, I can create a directory in C:\Users\John without any admin rights?

Comment: That is correct. Although you'd never hard code a path like that

Comment: Just making sure I understand what you mean by "hard code", do you mean that you'd get the username using some function and then assign to a variable called `Username`, then create the directory in `'C:\Users\' + Username`, or do you mean something different?

Comment: Don't create the folder in the profile directory. If it's for user documents, create it in the user's personal documents folder. If it's for application configuration data, create it in the user's roaming or local application data directory. Use the roaming directory if it makes sense for the data to follow the user around across machines in an organization that uses roaming profiles. OTOH, if it's a large amount of data or your application will be specific to a particular machine, then it makes more sense to use the local application data directory.

Comment: By not hard coding, I mean using the function that @IInspectable referred you to, passing the appropriate known folder ID for the location that you choose

Answer (score 1):

Without admin permissions the intended behavior is that you can write to the folders inside the user account folder.

C:\Users\%USERNAME%\

You can write to the documents, pictures and music sub folders, AppData\Roaming or AppData\Local\ etc...

As mentioned in the comments [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) is the preferred method to get these folder paths, here is a simple example:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <shlobj_core.h>

int main()
{
    PWSTR path = nullptr;

    SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, 0, &path);

    std::cout << path << std::endl;

    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```